# Is there a naming convention for new bash commands?

Tags: linux, bash, naming-conventions

When creating a new Bash command that has multiple words, such as remove-unused-scripts, is there a common naming convention? For instance, should it be remove-unused-scripts, or remove_unused_script, or removeUnusedScripts, or something else entirely?

I'm fairly new to Bash, just want to make sure I don't form any bad habits early on.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You aren't adding "bash commands". You are adding your own new command that can be run from the command line. So your naming convention should be internally consistent if you are adding multiple commands. Barring that I don't know of any over-arching pattern. Hit `<Tab><Tab>` at your shell prompt and see the list of possible completions for example.

Comment: usually, mixing cases is not welcome, all lowercase is conventional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think most languages recommend `remove_unused_script` over `removeUnusedScript` these days for readability. `remove-unused-scripts` is a legal *file* name for a script. `bash` allows function names to contain hyphens:

```
some-func () {
    echo hi
}
```

but that isn't portable; POSIX function names are restricted to letters, numbers, and `_`.

Answer (score 4):

https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml#Naming_Conventions suggests to use lowercase and some underscores. You can read the complete guide for more reasonable conventions, including examples.